# dynamic conditional formatting based on dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 7 Columns, 5 with data and the first two with names. Is there a formula I can use in **conditional formatting** where if I change my column from the drop-down, conditional formatting will look in that column and highlight the name with less than 25, and when i change the value of **Capture**, the purple highlight across the columns changes too?

[image].

Hope it makes sense

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you want to do. I'm guessing from your screenshot that you got columns and rows confused. It looks like you actually have 7 *columns*.

Comment: My bad yes I have 7 columns. When I change the capture (at the top) to 2 the purple highlight will go to mydc2. What I want is a conditional format where it works according to what column headng is highlighted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time when asking a question please make sure to include your own effort or at least tell people what you have tried or researched :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Capture** being the column number that you want to change dynamically;
- **ListFOR** being the list of names you have in the `FOR` column;
- **RngData** being the values in your table excluding the first column and column headers.

I will use the following example to demonstrate my answer:

[image: Demo]

> To highlight a specific column by changing **Capture** value:

1. Highlight range `B3:G10` (which is the 6 columns including headers on the right) with cell `B3` being the active cell;
2. Use the following formula as the **Formatting Rule** in conditional formatting and set the background color as desired:

   `=COLUMN(A$1)=Capture`

*The logic is to compare the value returned by **COLUMN** function with the **Capture** value, if they are the same i.e. `TRUE`, apply the conditional format.*

> To highlight a specific name or names with value less than `25` in the highlighted column from previous step:

1. Highlight range `A4:A10` (which is the first column without header) with cell `A4` being the active cell;
2. Use the following formula as the **Formatting Rule** in conditional formatting and set the background color as desired:

   `=INDEX(RngData<25,MATCH($A4,ListFOR,0),Capture)`

*The logic is to first convert the values into `TRUE` or `FALSE` by comparing them with `25`, then use **INDEX+MATCH** function to return the logical result based on the given name, if `TRUE` apply the conditional format.*

---

Here is a live demo:

[image: Live Demo]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: @MrN glad to help :) If you think my answer is working fine for you, please consider marking it as the solution by clicking the tick mark under the down-vote button next to my answer. Cheers :)